# React: why only the first item checkbox of an unordered list is triggered?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to render a list of tasks. every task should have a checkbox. I designed the checkbox using css. but now when I clicked on any checkbox, only first list items checkbox is triggered.

Todo Component

```
const Todo = ({ todo, toggleTodo }) => {
  return (
    <li className='listItem' key={todo.id}>
      <div className='round'>
        <input
          type='checkbox'
          id='checkbox'
          checked={todo.completed}
          onClick={() => toggleTodo(todo.id)}
        />
        <label for='checkbox'></label>
        <span className="todo__task">{todo.task}</span>
      </div>
    </li>
  );
};

export default Todo;
```

CSS

```
.round {
  position: relative;
}

.round label {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 20px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 20px;
}

.round label:after {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  content: '';
  height: 6px;
  left: 3px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  width: 12px;
}

.round input[type='checkbox'] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.round input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
    background-color: #66bb6a;
    border-color: #66bb6a;
  }
  
  .round input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

I want to checkbox to be triggered on every list item. how can I achieve that?

Comment: If the Todo component is reused, it might have something to do with the id="checkbox", id are supposed to be unique.

Comment: I assume `toggleTodo` is a function that will update the state. Can you make sure the `id` that you pass to the function is unique for each Todo? Otherwise, it may set the `completed` property for the wrong object.

Comment: thanks, both of you. my checkbox id was not unique.

Answer (score -1):

This should fix your problem:

```js
const Todo = ({ todo, toggleTodo }) => {
  return (
    <li className='listItem' key={todo.id}>
      <div className='round'>
        <input
          type='checkbox'
          id={todo.id} // <---
          checked={todo.completed}
          onClick={() => toggleTodo(todo.id)}
        />
        <label for='checkbox'></label>
        <span className="todo__task">{todo.task}</span>
      </div>
    </li>
  );
};

export default Todo;
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation as to how is fixes the problem?